# Handling timezones with daylight saving in C#

Tags: c#, .net, timezone

We have an application related to aviation, and specifically flights.

Times have to be stored in local, so I chose to use UTC Time + an offset, but then now I realize it is a bad choice:

By storing the timezone as an offset, I lose track of the original timezone and this has implications when dealing with daylight savings.

For example I can store a time in Alpine, UT as UTC time and a -6 offset and also a time in Phoenix, AZ as UTC time and a -6 offset.

But when daylight saving comes, the time will change in Alpine, but not in Phoenix.

So, I need to store the proper timezone and I have seen that there are also different lists with a different syntax, so I am assuming there are different standards.

In C#, what would be the best option to store a local time with the local time zone to make it work with daylight saving changes?

Comment: As you have too mentioned that storing local time is a bad choice , and I also agree with it. I would suggest that if you can start working changing your current program to store the UTC time zone (to have backward compatibility) you can store both UTC and local time zone value. That would you don't require to work on all the edge cases for what country has day light saving and when. You can rely on system dlls to convert the UTC value to local value based on regional settings of user.

Comment: "Times have to be stored in local". I'm really sorry for you. This right there is [the gate to madness.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY) Having to deal with daylight savings only makes the trip to madness faster. Please, take the advice of someone that have walked this road before, and for your own sanity - reconsider that approach.

Comment: The regional settings of the user are not relevant here because, in aviation, times displayed are always local to the location of the airport. The issue is that if the time is stored in UTC + Offset and the daylight saving kicks in, I can't do the correction since I don't know what zone that time belongs to if I only store an offset.

Comment: @Zohar: yes, that's why I wrote here :D I want to find out how to store it properly since UTC + Offset is not working for daylight saving

Comment: *Store* them in UTC, *display* them in local time. Convert when needed.

Comment: but what is "local"? Alpine is UTC - 6 + Daylight savings, Phoenix is UTC - 6 for example. So local is UTC + Offset + Daylight savings from the local area and I need to find how to store what 'local' means, in which zone it belongs in regards to daylight savings

Comment: You're displaying them on a client somewhere. Let the client tell you its time zone.

Comment: Not in aviation: if you are looking for a LA -> NY flight, the flight departure is LA time, the flight arrival is written as NY time, this is not related to the client.

Comment: Then you should look for a database of cities and their current time zones. There are things like https://www.worldtimeserver.com/ (and others), maybe one of them has a public api to use.

Comment: Just coming to this discussion.  I can tell you that the advice "always store in UTC" is not *always* correct.  Context matters significantly.  For example, if you are storing the time a plane departed or landed at an airport, then a UTC based time is preferred.  If one desires local time to be obvious, then a `DateTimeOffset` with the local time and the offset from UTC can be used instead.  HOWEVER, when describing a *future* time that a plane is scheduled to depart, such as in a passenger ticketing system, you should *not* use UTC, but rather the local time and time zone id or airport code.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the context in which your date/time values exist?  Are you tracking flights in progress (ex: from the pilot's or air traffic controller's viewpoint), or are you working with scheduled flight time tables (from the passenger's viewpoint)?

Comment: The flights are always scheduled in local time (pilot or passenger) so for example we get 6pm/New York. We used to convert all to UTC and this was working well to store past flights; now that we are adding current and future flights it’s more complex because it’s not just data we buy but also data that pilots provide us: if a pilot tells us 5pm / Salt Lake City, UT, we can’t just add +6 for UTC because we would not factor in daylight saving. So storing a time offset doesn’t work well either.

Comment: So ideally we need to know the time zone, not as an offset but as a literal “time” .... “zone” where we know the offset and daylight saving status of that zone. For example UT and AZ are both -6 but half the year they still have a different time. Once we have that UTC / Local becomes irrelevant because we can translate at will

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the discussion in the question's comments, I understand that you are working with flight time schedules - that is, the time a future flight is intended to depart.  This is indeed a case where the local time is more important than the UTC time.

Since you have the local time and location of departure (ex: 5:00 PM in Salt Lake City), then you should be storing in your database of scheduled departure times two values:

- `17:00`  - The relevant local time of the departure
- `SLC`    - The location where the time is relevant

If this is a *specific* occurrence of this flight, then you should store the date as well:

- `2018-06-01T17:00` - The *specific* relevant local time of the departure
- `SLC` - The location where the local time is relevent

**These are the details that are contextually relevant to your business use case.  Do not lose sight of them by converting them to UTC**.

That said, you might consider storing them as a `DateTimeOffset` (`2018-06-01T17:00-06:00`), which makes converting to UTC trivial for a given instance.  However there are two problems with this approach:

- It cannot work with recurrences, because the offset may change.
- Even for a single instance, the offset *might* change - if the government controlling the time zone decides to change their standard offset or daylight saving time rules before that occurrence takes effect.  If you do take a `DateTimeOffset` approach, or a UTC-based approach, you must be prepared to recalculate future events in the face of such changes.  (For more on this, see my blog articles: *[On the Timing of Time Zone Changes](https://codeofmatt.com/2016/04/23/on-the-timing-of-time-zone-changes/)* and *[Time Zone Chaos Inevitable in Egypt](https://codeofmatt.com/2016/07/01/time-zone-chaos-inevitable-in-egypt/)*.  There are countless other examples.)

With regards to the location - because you are working with data that is contextually applicable to the airline industry, I recommend using IATA airport codes like the `SLC` that I showed above.  In other contexts, one might store an IANA time zones identifier like `America/Denver`, or a Windows time zone identifier like `Mountain Standard Time`.

You may find [my "Airport Time Zones" gist  (code and output table)](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/6d219c48697c550c2476) useful for working with IATA airport codes.  You'll have to decide how that data will flow through your system.  If you are running on Windows and want to use the `TimeZoneInfo` class to convert times to different time zones, then use the Windows time zone IDs shown there.  If you want to use the IANA time zone IDs instead, consider using [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org), or you can use my [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter) library.  There are several different options here, so explore them all carefully and pick ones that make sense to you.

Noda Time would be a great choice, IMHO.  Not only would you get excellent time zone support, but you'd also be able to use types like `LocalTime` or `LocalDateTime` which align well with the scenarios described.

Comment: Well, I have to admit that this seems like it might be a better solution then what I'm suggesting. +1. One point for storing datetime in UTC is it simplifies the calculation of flight duration. I'm sure it can also be done if stored as local datetime, but it will probably be more complicated.

Comment: Indeed, by the time you get to calculating with these values, you must know the offset from UTC - which you can get through the `GetUtcOffset` or `ConvertTime*` methods on `TimeZoneInfo`, or through various Noda Time APIs.  However, from experience with these things, I'd suggest that in the airline industry one has to be careful about *calculating* the flight duration.  Instead, decide whether the departure time or the arrival time is authoritative, and apply the known flight duration to achieve the other.  In other words, `departure + duration = arrival`, not `arrival - departure = duration`.

Comment: Consider also the references I gave in the fifth update at the bottom of [my blog about the Egypt time zone changes in 2016](https://codeofmatt.com/2016/07/01/time-zone-chaos-inevitable-in-egypt/).  Emirates Airlines flight 926 left an hour early stranding 18 passengers.   Being a Dubai owned airline, they considered their *arrival* time to be more important, and did the math as `arrival - duration = departure`.  Since Egypt had modified their time zone DST rules at the last minute, the Dubai-based airline couldn't update their schedule in time.

Comment: Egyptian Air flights that day departed on time, but *arrived* an hour later than expected.   For either, online sites that had the old data and did `arrival - departure = duration` ended up calculating the flight time an hour short.

Comment: I often find it funny how regular math rules don't apply in real life... I have to admit that my advice is more general, as I have never worked on anything related to airline traffic (I did work on some international systems that takes data from many different sources all over the globe and had to synchronize all that salad into a well formed single framework though - and that's when UTC saved my sanity). Anyway, as I wrote in my previous comment, I think your answer is better than mine on this question.

Comment: Yep.  For those synchronization salad stories, UTC is king.  Especially things like log-file correlation.  Timestamping events in the present makes all such data *past* events, and thus all of the funny business with time zones becomes mostly irrelevant.  :)

Comment: Actually it was both past and future events. Not taking into account political madness such as the Egyptian chaos you blogged about or the kind of political madness we have in Israel almost every year regarding the daylight savings time. that client used to have their IT guy set the clocks manually at 02:00 to 01:00 or 03:00 twice a year... Indeed, Time and timezones do require a lot more then the average Joe would ever consider.

Answer (score 1):

As I wrote in my comment, **do not** store local dates. Instead, store datetime values as UTC, and convert to local datetime when you need to display it.
You can use the [`ConvertTimeFromUtc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc?view=netframework-4.7.1) method of the [`TimeZoneInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo?view=netframework-4.7.1) class for that.

This means you will have to also keep a list of locations and whatever TimeZoneInfo they are associated in - For example,
`Jerusalem` would be associated with `Israel Standard Time`,
`Rome` with `W. Europe Standard Time`,
`Hawaii` with `Hawaiian Standard Time`
and so on. (I'll bet you can find such a list online somewhere.)
Please note that the `ConvertTimeFromUtc` method handles the daylight savings problem for you as well.

Then you can do something like this to get the local time by location:

```
DateTime GetLocalDateByCityName(DateTime utc, string cityName)
{
    var timeZoneInfoId = GetTimeZoneInfoIdByCityName(string cityName);
    return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utc, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(timeZoneInfoId);
}
```

And of course, in `GetTimeZoneInfoIdByCityName` you get the TimeZoneInfoId for the specific city.

Comment: Let me give that a try; I need to check how extensive the city list is

Comment: And as Marvin wrote in his comment, there are websites dedicated to dealing with the timezone problem, Perhaps you can use a 3rd party API for that.

Comment: I was looking at NodaTime, as it seems like it could be helping in my situation.

Comment: Perhaps; I have no experience with NodaTime but I've been reading good things about it.

Comment: Noda Time would allow you to use standard IANA time zone identifiers, such as `"America/Los_Angeles"` or `"Asia/Jerusalem"`.  See "Time Zone Databases" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for more details.

Comment: Note, this answer is fine in terms of how to convert from UTC to local time in a specific Windows time zone, but it doesn't address the contextual concerns of the OP.  "Always UTC" is not the best advice.  It is applicable in *many* cases, but not all of them.

Comment: @MattJohnson  I agree it's not **always** the best option, but whenever you have to work with different time zones, I find it's best to have all your times stored in a single time zone that everyone can reference. UTC is just that.

Comment: Sure, but that logic falls apart in many cases.  Scheduling or working with scheduled times in the future is one of them.  Another is working with date-only values (such as birthdays).  There is a lot written about this already, so I'll not drone on.  Just be careful about any advice that says "always" - if there's more than one way to do something, there are probably edge cases that prefer or require that way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime to convert DateTime between time zones if you need to handle Daylight Savings.

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myDateTime, timeZone);

TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myDateTime, fromTimeZone, toTimeZone);
```